# 2- or -2 as superscript?

Tags: structural-formula

When writing the formula for an ion, should the operator come before or after the number that indicates the ion's charge?

Here are some examples:

$\ce{SO_4^{-2}}$ or $\ce{SO_4^{2-}}$
$\ce{Fe^{+2}}$ or $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$

I'm not great at chemistry, so I'm sorry if it's a stupid question.

I just haven't been able to find many answers.

Comment: $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$

Comment: @MaxW I have made your absolutely correct comment into an answer. I hope you do not mind.  Just trying to return friendly answers to new users. Can delete it if you feel uncomfortable

Answer (score 5):

As @MaxW has said in comments, the correct form is:

$\ce{SO_4^{2-}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$

It is just as in math. 
If you have $a+a$ it results in $2a$, not $a2$, and thus:

$\ce{SO_4^{--}=SO_4^{2-}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{++}=Fe^{2+}}$

It is not a stupid question.
IMHO it is a perfectly legitimate question. 
I apologize for those who are downvoting your question.

Comment: Last I checked it was `-1 + -1 = -2` not `1- + 1- = 2-`, so "just as in math" is a slightly flimsy argument.

Comment: @R.M. $a+a=2a$. Charges are entities, not numbers.

Comment: My point was that "just as in math" is somewhat dismissive, as you can come to the exact opposite conclusion from math conventions from the `-1 + -1 = -2` argument (which is probably where most people who want to put the sign in front of the number get it from). -- "Charges are entities, not numbers" might be the rationale, but currently it appears nowhere in your answer.